# Are anions stronger bases than (different) neutral molecules?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

I need to compare the basicity of 2 molecules: a negatively charged $\ce{O}$ attached to a *t*-butyl (*t*-butoxide), and a neutral $\ce{N}$ with 3 ethyls attached to it (triethylamine).

These are completely different molecules, so by instinct, I would say that the one with the negative charge is probably more basic. But, is there a more formal way of figuring it out (not experimentally)?

Comment: I would like to tell you that every negatively charged molecule is more basic than a neutral one, but sadly it's not (for comparison, ammonia and alkylamines are generally more basic than a deprotonated beta-diketone).
I guess that you are at the beginning of your career, but it's highly advisable to learn some key pka values for some compounds/functional groups. You will later learn how to guess if a compound has higher or lower basicity than a similar one, but a mnemonical reference is precious

Comment: You need to compare the pKa for the two compounds. This chart has a substantial list of pKa values including those you are looking for http://evans.rc.fas.harvard.edu/pdf/evans_pKa_table.pdf

Comment: Ok, thanks guys! Yes, seems like a good idea to have some pKa references memorized and guesstimate that of related compounds from there.